# how to create a texture like granite?

Tags: texturing, materials

I want to create a granite tile design in blender.
But I dont know how to get the white dot like pattern on my mesh ( like in the picture attached).

Someone please tell me how to acheive this.[image: Granite]

Comment: Hi, welcome to blender.se. Could you make your title more specific to your problem?

Comment: there is a lot of information available to you in this site already. Use the search box at the top. https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=granite

Comment: Don't do that! Do not change the question to a different one than the one asked originally. Please make another post with new questions.

Comment: I was trying to post a new question but i was unable to add a new question @susu

Comment: Please roll back the text. Otherwise the answer below does not apply anymore as it was meant for a different question.

Answer (score 4):

Using this texture (https://freepbr.com/materials/polished-granite-top-pbr-material/) and this node configuration

[image]

you can get something like this (you'll need some minor fix, but feel free to try and comment this answer to get further support)

[image]

- Texture coordinate: this node is useful to tell how the texture should be placed on the mesh (UV setting refers to how the mesh is unwrap in 2d)
- mapping: this node is used to scale the texture, rotate or move it
- texture image: you choose the image you want to use to "colorize" the mesh
- color ramp: this is used here only cause the original texture is white with black dots and you need black texture with white dots. You can control black and white stops to find best results
- principled BSDF: this is a shader that contains some attributes to tell blender engine how to render the "colors"
- material output: this is mandatory node used to tell Blender that all the settings are applied to the surface of the object

Comment: Can you please explain what the nodes are doing and how to choose the values, like why the color ramp. It might be obvious to you, but new users will not be able to apply this in other context otherwise.

Comment: done, only for you! :)

Comment: and for the community! : )  thanks.